# Nagios, Is it possible to monitor file modification?

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to monitor file modification of `/etc/passwd`, is it possible to do that with Nagios?
I'm not looking for file modification time, but for file changed or not...
Do you know any way to do it or shall I write a check_command myself?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if md5sum check is enough for you you might want to try following plugin:

[nagios-exchange check_file_md5](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Security/check_file_md5/details)

From the manual:

> Modeled after check_file_md5s, this script performs the following functions:
>
> - Permits arbitrary md5sum checking of a filename passed in on a parameter
> - Builds a list of files with every md5 check - warns when file isn't in the list and adds the file
> - Critical alert when a file is not present
> - Critical alert, followed by a refresh of the list of checksums when an md5 checksum doesn't match